# Assign ticket to a specific Zendesk Support group with Sunshine Conversation

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api

I am currently using Sunshine Conversation to integrate a chatbot to Zendesk Support. Currently, we're only using users, conversation and messages endpoints.

One of the requirements of the integration is that every ticket has to be assigned to a specific Zendesk Support group, depending on some conditions.

The problem is, the Sunshine Conversation API doesn't offer a way to specify the group id when creating the conversation.

I'm trying to map SC conversations to Zendesk tickets and then use Zendesk API to change the ticket's group id. But can't find a reliable mechanism to do the mapping, because SC conversations are converted to a Zendesk ticket when the first message is sent, but even more, conversation ids from Sunshine Conversation API and ticket ids from Zendesk API are different.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved using Switchboard integrations. Followed these instructions and the send group id when passing control to the Agent Workspace

https://docs.smooch.io/guide/switchboard/#zendesk-system-fields